# Why is my TestNG dataprovider website blocking?

Tags: java, testng, selenium-grid, testng-dataprovider

I'm using TestNG, Selenium Grid and using the `@dataprovider` annotation to read my testcase values from an Excel sheet. I am testing two sites that offer the same products using the same field names etc., but just under different brand names.

Site A processes without any issues whereas site B seems to be aware that an automation script is been run on it and redirects to a contact screen preventing me from completing a test case. When I log on manually, I can proceed without any problem.

My question is, are there tools that can prevent the use of the data injection with the `@dataprovider` annotation, and, if so, is there any way around them?

Comment: Have you compared request headers sent when you test manually and with the automation? Some proxies/firewalls interpret absent information in request headers as bots.

Comment: Thanks Flavio, No i haven't tried this...im pretty new to the whole world of automation...How do i go about compareing the request headers...

Comment: For manual test you can use Firebug (FF plugin), Developer Tools (Chrome), etc. For automated test, I believe, Selenium has a configuration to turn on debug log and save request headers.